# hibernate hql and setMaxResults

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, rownum

I've got some quarrels with hibernate.
My query, yet optimized, is quite heavy. One of my optimization consist on limiting the resultset returned.
So with hibernate I've used the method setMaxResultSet, but I hit the same problem described in this post:

[Hibernate: Pagination with setFirstResult and setMaxResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396799/hibernate-pagination-with-setfirstresult-and-setmaxresult)

(the issue is that using setMaxResultSet hibernate in some cases wrap the query like this:

`select * from (your query) where rownum <= :rownum`)

So, the solution in that case was to add an **orderBy**, bu I've millions of records and an orderBy kills the execution time of the query.
I've managed to overcome the problem using the **createNativeQuery** and passing the exact query I need (something like "`my query where rownum <= :rownum" instead of "select * from (your query) where rownum <= :rownum", and goodbye portability`), but honestly I don't get why Hibernate acts like this...

As the previous post suggests, hibernate resolve an SQL like that as long as your query "is not stable" because, if I haven't misunderstand, the order of the records may not be the same between two executions, but I don't get how that method could solve this stability problem.

Comment: It's simple: if you have `where rownum <= :rownum` in the query, the restriction is applied *before* applying the `order by`. So, whatever the order you might use on the query, it would always return the same first rows. That's clearly not what you want: if you order by name, you want the first names first, and only the N first ones. Not arbitrary N first rows, ordered by name.

Comment: I don't think it work this way... From what I could see trying the query directly on the db, adding the orderBy operator again kill the execution time, so it seems that rownum is applied after the orderBy (I suppose the db is trying to fetch and order all the records that match the query and then order them to return the first N)

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same pagination in hibernate.the HQL is given below.it may be useful for you.

(i) initially you should use this Query

```
List<Object> Entity_Cls_Lst= Objclass.createQuery("from library where book_id>Book_ID order by book_id").list();
```

(ii) after scrolling you should take last result data's Book_ID  and pass to the query in where condition.

```
  List<Object> Entity_Cls_Lst= Objclass.createQuery("from library where book_id>Book_ID order by book_id").setMaxResults(MAX_RECORDS).list();
```

Comment: I see a couple of problems about your solution, the first is that I can't use order By operator, because it make the query fatally slow, and so I can neither use the ID as a filter, cause the ids of my record are not ordered.

Comment: I have used solution posted here, it fails sometime and gives incorrect order by results  because its similar to SQL:

select * from (your query) where rownum <= :rownum

And above query does not guarantee result will be given rownum as per ordered criteria. Easier way is to handle ordered result while iterating on java side.